# CSS - Default content to disappear when tabs are clicked

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation witch has to be accomplished 100% in pure CSS no JS included.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hen75c3g/3/

Now when I load the page the default content is displayed. Also when i click on first tab the right content is displayed. I am interested when I click on other tabs the default content to disappear and the related content to appear.

This has to be done only in CSS so no Javascript has to be involved. Can this be done?

```css
    .accordion {
        width:830px;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:10px auto;
        color:#474747;
        padding:10px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    .accordion section h2 {
        display:none;
    }
    .accordion section h2 a {
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin:10px;
        padding:10px;
        font-size:12px;
        color: #000;
        text-decoration:none;
        width:100%;
    }
    .accordion section p {
        display:none;
    }
    .accordion section:after {
        font-size:24px;
        color:#fff;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    .accordion section h2 {
        position:relative;
    }
    .accordion section p.default {
        clear:both;
        display:block;
    }
    .accordion section:target p {
        clear:both;
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="_m-container">
        <div class="accordion">
            <ul class="_m-menu">
                <li><a href='#tab-1'>Tab 1</a>
    
                </li>
                <li><a href='#tab-2'>Tab 2</a>
    
                </li>
                <li><a href='#tab-3'>Tab 3</a>
    
                </li>
            </ul>
            <section id='tab-1'>
                 <h2><a href='#tab-1'>Option 1</a></h2>
    
                <p class='default'>Tab1 content.</p>
            </section>
            <section id='tab-2'>
                 <h2><a href='#tab-2'>Option 2</a></h2>
    
                <p>Tab 2 content.</p>
            </section>
            <section id='tab-3'>
                 <h2><a href='#tab-3'>Option 3</a></h2>
    
                <p>Tab3 content .</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the result there is not what I need. It redirects to #target1 by default and this is not what I try to achieve

Comment: Look at the examples in the top answer - they do nearly exactly what you're wanting. Even if they're not *exactly* what you want, the essential question is still the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this can be done in css. I think the closest solution to a pure css tab implementation would be on hover.

But, to achieve what you're looking for with jQuery, you could do the following:
(note that I've added some classes to the elements, see http://jsfiddle.net/hen75c3g/18/)

```
$('.accordion').on('click', '.tab-link', function(){
// store the href as a variable
var tabSelector = $(this).attr('href');    

// hide the previously visible div
$('.tab-content').removeClass('active');

// add active class
$(tabSelector).addClass('active');

return false;

});
```